# Is Least Upper Bound of Empty Set equal to Greatest Lower Bound of a another Set?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

We had this discussion today that $\operatorname{LUB}(\varnothing) = \operatorname{GLB}(L)$ in a complete lattice $(L,\leq)$. 
I'm not still not getting it why that is the case.

Answer (score 3):

The minimal element of the lattice is greater than every element in the empty set (in which there are none), and every element that is greater than every element in the empty set (which is every element) is greater than the minimal element. Therefore by definition it is the least upper bound of the empty set.

Comment: So least upper bound or greatest lower bound of empty set is nothing. But Greatest lower bound of non-empty set is at least something. So how is nothing same as something?

Comment: As my answer explains the least upper bound of the empty set is not nothing, it is the minimal element, and the greatest lower bound is the maximal element.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of vacuous truth.

In other words, if the minimum element of $L$ is not the least upper bound of $\varnothing$, then we should find a counterexample of some element in $\varnothing$... oh wait. We can't find such counterexample! So it must be the least upper bound.